# Query for aggregating data from table with columns from other tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to come up with a few different basic sql querys that I can incorporate into a website with some dropdowns to fill in the selection variables. But I'm not sure how to make the queries structured with my table layout.

I have some tables:

```
"lineage_data" = lineage of each unit        Relevant fields:  unit, level3
"unit_Data" = unit data per sample           Relevant fields: unit, sample name, binary
"Sample_Data" = metadata                     Relevant fields: sample name, region
```

lineage data

```
unit   level 1   level 2   level 3
54      square    box       cube
63      square    box       cube
78      square    box       triangle
```

unit data (This table is millions of rows long.)

```
unit   sample name   binary
54     sample 1      1
63     sample 1      1
63     sample 2      1
78     sample 2      1
54     sample 3      1
78     sample 3      1
```

sample data

```
sample name   region
sample 1      x
sample 2      y
sample 3      x
```

The query I want to construct is to create a summary list by sample of how many binary positives for units with the level “cubes” are in samples from region x

So the result would be something like:

```
Region X
Unit Level: CUBES
Sample 1: 2
Sample 3: 1
```

I’m assuming there are some joins and a count distinct….but I have no clue how to make something that complicated.

Ultimately I envision using some html/jquery to allow a user to populate a region list, sample list, level list, etc for data they would like to see, and upon submission the variables would be passed off to another script that would gather the data. Or I may just do some canned static querys in R and just display the results without any interaction.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: I can add some sample data, but I did have a desired result up there already.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Updated, hopefully that makes it a little clearer.

Comment: Do you understand the user of `JOIN`?  If so, write the query that will gather the data from the various tables.  Then we can discuss the "summarization" using `GROUP BY` and `SUM()`.

Comment: I've used joins when working with smaller datasets, but I was worried that it would likely be incredibly slow trying to join these three tables?  There are about 60,000 distinct units and thousands of samples.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  s.region AS Region,l.level3 AS UnitLevel,    
  u.samplename,SUM(u.binary)    
FROM unit_data u    
  LEFT JOIN Sample_Data s ON s.samplename = u.samplename    
  LEFT  JOIN lineage_data l ON l.unit= u.unit AND l.level3='CUBE'    
GROUP BY s.region,u.samplename;
```